# How to iterate XQuery Path?

Tags: xquery, soapui

```
<Response xmlns="https://**********/token">
   <rows>
      <e>
         <e>1,4507</e>
         <e>1</e>
         <e>2017-02-28T05:10:32.0606654Z</e>
         <e>2017-02-28T05:10:32.2267838Z</e>
         <e>Depart</e>
         <e>Depart</e>
         <e>acct: xxx on 10/2/2015</e>
         <e>16.666131292069704</e>
         <e null="true"/>
         <e>Open</e>
         <e null="true"/>
         <e null="true"/>
         <e null="true"/>
      </e>
      <e>
         <e>1,4507</e>
         <e>2</e>
         <e>2017-02-28T05:10:32.0606654Z</e>
         <e>2017-02-28T05:10:32.2267838Z</e>
         <e>Depart</e>
         <e>Depart</e>
         <e>acct: xxx on 10/2/2015</e>
         <e>16.666131292069704</e>
         <e null="true"/>
         <e>Open</e>
         <e null="true"/>
         <e null="true"/>
         <e null="true"/>
      </e>
   </rows>
   <skip>0</skip>
   <take>126</take>
</Response>
```

The above is my xml response:

I wanted to verify each row that status is Open.

Open

```
declare namespace ns1='https://**********/token';
<Result>
for  $x in //ns1:Response[1]/ns1:rows[1]
return data($x/ns1:e[1]/ns1:e[10]/text())
</Result>
```

but it is not returning the value.. It just gives the following in the expected result.

```
<Result>for  $x in //ns1:Response[1]/ns1:rows[1]
return data($x/ns1:e[1]/ns1:e[2]/text())</Result>
```

Is it correct xquery expression? would be helpful if some check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your XQuery expression in `{}` otherwise it will be treated as string literal :

```
declare namespace ns1='https://**********/token';
<Result>
{
    for  $x in //ns1:Response[1]/ns1:rows[1]
    return data($x/ns1:e[1]/ns1:e[10]/text())
}
</Result>
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/5e2e5b829f4afb1bd65f6a495cd44379)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<Result>Open</Result>
```

It isn't clear what is the expected output exactly though, since you've been using exact index on every path step which will cause the expression to match only one element at a time...

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know that every row has `e[10] = "Open"` then you can do:

```
<Result>{empty(/ns1:Rows/*/*[10][.!="Open"])}</Result>
```

(Your question title talks of iterating. That's procedural thinking. In XQuery, just like in SQL, you generally operate on sets of items directly: you don't need to iterate over them to process them one at a time.)

Comment: this one sounds correct to me as i have to do assertion.. :)